# Convert value to json/object and update entry

Tags: javascript, json

I've the following  value "string like" and I want to update some value inside ,
How should I do that ?

This is how I see it in the debugger

```
 var aa =   "'[{key:10,key2:20}]'\r"
```

I need to change the value of key to 5 how should I do that (assume that I have more keys).

I try with `JSON.parse(aa)` and I got error

I try also with  `aa[0].key = 5` ; which doesnt work either,

any idea how to overcome this ?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not valid JSON. However, you can _probably_ `eval('temp=' + aa)` it, though I discourage using `eval` whenever possible.

Comment: `eval(eval("'[{key:10,key2:20}]'\r"))`. *Shudders*.

Comment: You could write your own parser, it doesn't look that hard if the input is that simple. The RegExp constructor might help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you provided looks like some console log, it's not a valid json string. But it can possibly be transformed in to a valid one.

This would work for some simple cases which may just fit your need.

```js
var aa = "'[{key:10,key2:20}]'\r";
var lead = aa.match(/^\s*['"]/)[0];
var trail = aa.match(/['"]\s*$/)[0];
aa = aa.substr(lead.length, aa.length - trail.length - 1);
aa = aa.replace(/(\w+):/g, '"$1":');
var json = JSON.parse(aa);
json[0].key = 5;
var log = document.getElementById('log');
log.innerText = lead + JSON.stringify(json) + trail;
log.innerText += '\ntrail.length = ' + trail.length;
```

```html
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

Code updated. Well, I know you don't see the trailling '\r'. Don't worry, it's still there as you can see the length of trail is 2.

Comment: Thanks 1+ After I update the property I need to update the original property ,how can I do that ? in your code you put var aa = "'[{key:10,key2:20}]'\r"; but assume that I got the value from other property ..Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks but how you update the original value with the new property ?

Comment: For example assume that aa = value; value is coming as parameter with the value I put on the post and now I need to update it ...Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86797/discussion-between-voidx-and-mark).

Comment: To modify the value of a variable whose value is of type string your have to assign an other value to it as strings in javascript are immutable. There is no way to "MODIFY" a string.

Answer (score 3):

You can't parse with  `\r` because is not a valid json string. First of all replace it and then try to parse (note that keys are with `"`):

```
 var aa =   '[{"key":10,"key2":20}]\r'.replace("\r", "");
 JSON.parse(aa);
```

See the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yr0u04cu/

Comment: This is great, if OP has control over the input. But (and maybe I'm making an assumption) it doesn't look they do.

Comment: Thanks but I try it and in the JSON.parse I got error [SyntaxError: Unexpected token '],any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you have no control over the input, you may have to resort to using `eval()` (though I **strongly** discourage it for security reasons). If at all possible, it's best to find a way to get the original input to confirm to JSON.

Having said that, this worked for me:

```js
// Original string
var aa = "'[{key:10,key2:20}]'\r";

// First, cleanup the trailing \r
aa = aa.trim(); // may need to polyfill `.trim()`

// Need to get it to a JSO (JavaScript object)
var temp;
// Assign temp the value of your string.
eval('temp='+aa);
// next, evaluate that string as a JSO.
temp = eval(temp);

// make your changes
temp[0].key = 5;

// restore aa
aa = "'" + JSON.stringify(temp) + "'\r";

// output to the <pre> for visibility
document.getElementById('out').textContent = aa;
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: But the result is different to the input. You're assuming (perhaps correctly, perhaps not) that the \r is unwanted and that the different syntax resulting from JSON.stringification is acceptable.

Comment: @RobG: Shy of creating a parser, any of these solutions are going to come up short. We're also looking at the problem through a monocle, and can only make educated guesses as the the other moving piece(s).

Comment: Thanks this is working! there is a way to do it without eval ?

Comment: @Mark: You can use string methods and replace the value. But, at the end of the day (without a formal parser) that will be decent at best, and certainly will not be perfect.

Comment: The problem is the use of eval :(  I cannot use it since we have some static check and security check, can you please give some alternative ?

Comment: Btw using evel in server code (nodejs) is a problem ?

Comment: Because eval executes strings, it's considered a security concern (and for good reason). There's nothing wrong with the method itself, it's just that you can get into trouble if you can't validate what's being passed to it. And yes, nodejs can use eval.

Comment: What should I validate here ? 2. node JS can use eval without security danger ?

Comment: @BradChristie—yes, we're all stumbling in the dart as the OP hasn't provided enough information.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the variance in the input, plain string methods might be suitable. However that depends on the types of keys that might be used and the `\r` is stripped by the string manipulation.

```js
    function replaceKeyValue(s, key, value) {

      // Build a regular expression to match the key and its value
      var re = new RegExp('(\\W)' + key + ':[^,]+');

      // Replace the key with its new value
      return s.replace(re, '$1' + key + ':' + value);
    }

    var s = "'[{key:10,key2:20}]'\r";
    
    document.write(replaceKeyValue(s, 'key', 5)); // '[{key:5,key2:20}]'
```

Comment: Thanks Rob I've tried your code and its not working,Im still see the same value for the key,any idea what is missing ?

Comment: Assume that I got the value as in post as parameter and I need to update it as is,how should I do that ?

Comment: My understanding of the OP is that you want to modify the string exactly as this answer does. If that isn't what you want, please provide more information. Do you want to turn it into an object? Valid JSON?

Comment: Hi Rob,sorry for delay :) I try your code and it doesnt work...Can you please provide JSFiddler example?

Comment: Your question was "*I need to change the value of key to 5*", the answer changes "key:10" to "key:5" without changing the string to any other type.